# How to debug `attempt to apply non-function` error that only occurs when executing script from cmd line

Tags: r

I have an R script that runs perfectly when copy pasted into an R session.

However, when I try to run the script from the command line (i.e., `Rscript mycode.R`) I keep getting an error `attempt to apply non-function`.

The error is coming from a function that uses [AzureGraph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureGraph/index.html) and [AzureAuth](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureAuth/index.html) to fetch data from a Microsoft cloud directory. I can provide more detail about this function if needed, but my question is really more general.

1. What could cause this difference in behaviour between executing in an active R session vs. running the script from the command line.
2. What is the best strategy to debug this? Normally I would step through code in an R session to locate and fix errors, but obviously that will not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities:

- You have objects (functions, packages) in your interactive R session's environment that are not present in the session spawned by `Rscript`, for example because you automatically restore your R workspace at startup. Possible check: you can use `sessionInfo()` to see packages that are loaded and/or attached and `ls()` to list environment objects.
- You have multiple R installations on your system, and the RScript command is somehow mapping to a different one than your interactive session, which is missing some packages or functions. Possible check: the `version` function.
- The defaults of RScript are slightly different from those of an interactive session (for example, "save" and "restore" are typically disabled) and this is somehow affecting your script. Possible solution: try to add the `--restore` argument to the Rscript call.

How to debug? If you're going blind, good old bisection. Take your script, comment out the bottom half, see if it runs. Repeat iteratively (uncomment half of the commented section if it runs, comment out half of the uncommented section if not) until you find the line where the error is.

You can also run an individual line of code from Rscript using `Rscript -e "some code"` if you want to quickly check if a specific call is causing problems.

Comment: thanks Ottie, very useful. I will investigate your bullet points later today. On the bisection idea, this is where I'm struggling. I know exactly which line of code is causing the error, but I don't know why. In other languages I would insert a break function to halt execution and jump into a session to inspect what variables etc, are in memory. My suspicion is either an env variable is not being read or an Azure auth token is not returning correctly. Is there anyway to halt Rscript execution at a specified point in the code?

Comment: `stop("Right now!")` will halt execution.  (You can put in another message, or a variable to print if you like.)